# consume a third-party api in serenity-platform

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, serenity-platform

How can I consume a third-party api in serenity-platform and display the values on my dialog? And how can I call serenity-platform repository function from other app?  Any sample please. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Using other applications API is a simple webrequest call call you can write it in endpoint and give a call to it as a ServiceEndpoint call

For Serenity API's sample call for auth will be
https://domainname.com/Account/Login
Parameters:
{
Username: admin
Password: serenity
}

https://domainname.com/Default/Services/Orders/List - will give you list of all orders

Answer (score 0):

You can consume like other api's. Check request responses from chrome network for easy understand objects what you need. There is no sample for this what I know.